# Calling redis-cli in docker-compose setup

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I run the official Redis image https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/ in a `docker-compose` setup.

```
myredis:
  image: redis
```

How can run `redis-cli` with docker-compose on that image?
I tried the following, but it didn't connect:

```
docker-compose run myredis redis-cli
> Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refuse
```

The docs of the image says that I should run:

```
docker run -it --rm \
--link some-redis:redis \
redis \
sh -c 'exec redis-cli -h "$REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR" -p "$REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT"'
```

How does this translate to `docker-compose run`?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

That would override [the default `CMD [ "redis-server" ]`](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/94e9dcaaa93312651e91815fe7e4c5ef0f266408/2.6/Dockerfile): you are trying to run `redis-cli` on a container where the `redis-server` was never executed.

[As mentioned here](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis#step-2-run-redis-as-a-client-and-link-to-our-server), you can also test with:

```
docker exec -it myredis redis-cli
```

From docker-compose, as mentioned [in this docker/compose issue 2123](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2123#issuecomment-144756464):

```
rcli:
  image: redis:latest
  links:
    - redis
  command: >
     sh -c 'redis-cli -h redis '
```

> This should also works:

```
rcli:
  image: redis:latest
  links:
    - redis
  command: redis-cli -h redis
```

As the [OP ivoba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541949/ivoba) confirms ([in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304388/calling-redis-cli-in-docker-compose-setup/33305264?noredirect=1#comment54410016_33305264)), the last form works.
Then:

```
docker-compose run rcli
```

ivoba also adds:

> `docker-compose run redis redis-cli -h redis` works also when the containers are running.
>   This way its not necessary to declare a separate `rcli` container.

Comment: Great! works. I took the last approach and run it with: docker-compose run rcli

Comment: @ivoba Excellent! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: 'docker-compose run redis redis-cli -h redis' works also when the containers are running. This way its not necessary to declare a seperate rcli container.

Comment: @ivoba OK. I have again included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: `docker-compose run redis redis-cli -h redis` gives me a `Could not connect to Redis at redis:6379: Try again` :/ It also happens when the container is running. Edit: the solution with `rcli` works however. I guess this is related to networking somehow.

Comment: @EricBurel 3+ years later... I suppose so. If the issue persists, try and ask a new question (with your current version of Docker used, on which OS)

Answer (score 9):

You can also use this command:

```
docker-compose run myredis redis-cli -h myredis
```

Comment: this is already said in above answer just with different names

Answer (score 1):

I followed as @VonC suggest, but in my case I run redis on predefined network so it did not worked.

So in the case redis container run in specific network, `network` field should be specified in docker-compose.yaml file

```
rcli:
  image: redis:latest
  links:
    - redis
  command: redis-cli -h redis
  networks: 
    - <network redis run on>
```