# Unable to connect to Redis from Docker

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

Something simillar ([Unable to connect to MYSQL from Docker Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53582401/unable-to-connect-to-mysql-from-docker-instance?noredirect=1#comment94028964_53582401) and [redis connect timeout to remote server in a docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784812/redis-connect-timeout-to-remote-server-in-a-docker) and [Calling redis-cli in docker-compose setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304388/calling-redis-cli-in-docker-compose-setup)) I tried to run for the Redis on Docker.

I start the **Docker service** like this: `docker run --name some-redis -d redis`

Output:

```
docker run --name some-redis -d redis
d2ea8a77ba543b3e85020de6bc450e0d50ce9f60e0307e52fd4ae394bd29722
```

I re-verified using

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                       PORTS                               NAMES
d2ea8a77ba54        redis                       "docker-entrypoint.sh"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes                 6379/tcp                            some-redis
1be4f5dde2fb        mysql/mysql-server:latest   "/entrypoint.sh mysql"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour (healthy)   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   mysql
e7d9e3713f5c        ubuntu                      "/bin/bash"              6 days ago          Up 6 days                                                        angry_hodgkin
```

When I execute the below commands, its not working

```
docker exec -it redis redis-cli
Error response from daemon: No such container: redis
```

Comment: Didn't you explicitly name your container: some-redis? (--name some-redis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You named your container `some-redis` and are trying to connect with the name `redis`.

Try `docker exec -it some-redis redis-cli`